How to identify cause of super-slow right-click context menu in Windows 11?
My right-click menu usually takes 20-30 seconds to open. For some file types it is much quicker - e.g. 2-3 seconds. I've been trying to work out which shell extension(s) are causing the problem, but have had no luck.
For example, this context menu opens really quickly:

But this takes 25 seconds to open:

Any idea how I can diagnose the problem with the 2nd context menu - i.e. identify which extension is causing the delay?

Does this answer your question? How to diagnose right-click menu slowness?

Thanks. I tried disabling extensions one at a time using ShellExView but couldn't get to the root of the problem. I have now restored my system to a backup from last week, and the problem seems to have gone. For now, at least....

Use ShellExView or ShellMenuView to disable the unecessary programs that have shell extension entries in the context menu. Also, it is possible to disable shell extensions via Autoruns - Sysinternals in the 'Explorer' tab.
For example in ShellExView, select the appropriate software, right click and 'Disable selected items'.
